# Resize a Flash object via jQuery onload of page

Tags: jquery, flash, html, jwplayer

I'm using the HTML5 JW Player. It sizes the HTML5 video correctly, but shrinks the Flash fallback player; here's an example page: [Test Page](http://www.unctv.org/tWxkBbq_10M6wKRRL/t/home19_slider.htm#panel-5)

If you view that page in IE, you'll notice that on panel 5, the video is smaller than the space it's supposed to occupy. On Firefox, it works fine because it's using the OGG video in its HTML5 video player.

Is there a way to resize the Flash video via JavaScript/jQuery to fit the same space as the HTML5 video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?:

```
embed {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick: embed, object {height:233px !important}
The video tag's height is 209 and this will override that for the embed and object tags.

Comment: Should I include "object" in the CSS rule?

Comment: Yes, if that's what's used by the player. Anyway even if it's not used there's no harm in including it, so just include it.